# Can static_cast turn a non-null pointer into a null pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, static-cast

I need to write code for a callback function (it will be called from within ATL, but that's not really important):

```
HRESULT callback( void* myObjectVoid )
{
    if( myObjectVoid == 0 ) {
       return E_POINTER;
    }
    CMyClass* myObject = static_cast<CMyClass*>( myObjectVoid );
    return myObject->CallMethod();
}
```

here the `void*` is guaranteed to be a pointer to `CMyClass`, so `static_cast` is legal. My concern is the code must be as portable (to newer versions of Visual C++ at least) as possible. So to be super-paranoic I'm inclined to check the `CMyClass*` pointer as well - I mean what if it turns out to be null?

```
    if( myObjectVoid == 0 ) {
       return E_POINTER;
    }
    CMyClass* myObject = static_cast<CMyClass*>( myObjectVoid );
    if( myObject == 0 ) {
       return E_POINTER;
    }
```

Is the second check reasonable? Is it possible for `static_cast` to turn a non-null pointer into a null pointer?

Comment: Why not just cast unconditionally, and check for null after the cast? static_cast isn't going to dereference the pointer.

Comment: @Logan Capaldo: It feels better to check as early as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

static_cast can change the pointer value, if you cast between object parts on different offsets:

```
class A{ int x; }; class B{ int y; };
class C : A,B {};

C *c=new C(); 

B *b=c; 
// The B part comes after the A part in C. Pointer adjusted

C *c2=static_cast<C*>(b); 
// Pointer gets adjusted back, points to the beginning of the C part
```

However, "The null pointer value (4.10) is converted to the null pointer value of the
destination type." (5.2.9-8), i.e. *if* `c` is `NULL`, then `b` is also `NULL` (and not adjusted) and thus `c2` is set to `NULL`. The whole thing means: if static casting a non-NULL `myObjectVoid` yields `NULL`, then the value of `myObjectVoid` was obtained by circumventing the type system somehow. And it means, that the compiler might throw your second check away because "it can't happen anyway".

Answer (score 9):

No. If the pointer refers to a valid object, and the conversion is valid, then the result will also refer to a valid object, so it won't be null. If either is invalid, then the code is incorrect and the result is undefined. So the only way for valid usage to give a null result is to start with null.

In the specific case of converting between object pointers and void pointers, the standard has this to say (5.2.9/10):

> A value of type "pointer to object" converted to "pointer to `void`" and back to the original pointer type will have its original value.

and this (4.10/3)

> The result of converting a "pointer to T" to a "pointer to `void`" points to the start of the storage location where the object of type T resides

so the original and final object pointers will be the same, and the `void` pointer will be null if and only if the object pointers are.

Answer (score 0):

The only change `static_cast` should make to a pointer is for word-alignment.  So, in theory, of `myObjectVoid` pointed to the last byte in memory, it's possible that it might be 'aligned-up" to 0, but I don't see that as a realistic concern.

Comment: If this was possible, wouldn't it be a huge problem ? I always thought that 0 was the only value that a valid pointer couldn't have.

Comment: The real question is would the address be rounded up or down or is it implementation defined?

Answer (score 0):

No, the second check is not reasonable. It is not possible for `static_cast` to turn a non-null pointer into a null pointer. The only thing `static_cast` may change about the supplied value in your case (being a pointer) is to adjust the address. Otherwise it's strictly concerned with advising the rest of the compiler's type analysis that the result of the expression should be treated as the target type. For a pointer, that means that dereferencing finds the right address within the target object, and that increment and decrement strides are appropriate to the type's size.

Comment: Well there you go. In non real-world scenarios, passing in a carefully crafted pointer to static_cast could cause it to be adjusted by an offset that makes it NULL. Of course, that's never going to happen in real life.